# magento 2 cookie issue customer can't log in multistore and multidomain setup

Tags: magento2, multistore, multidomain

I have 2 domains in the same project first is https://site.domain.com/ and the other is https://site.example.co.uk/. Whenever I try to log in on https://site.example.co.uk/ it redirects me to the login page. I think I have an issue in the cookie domain. currently, it is blank,I tried to change it by looking at some answers, but still no luck.[image]